# CPU Usage based on eBPF profiling

Tags: kernel, monitoring, cpu-usage, ebpf

I am relatively new to the concept of eBPF and have, so far, been working with the BCC library. I've found the profile.py tool, alongside with FlameGraphs, to be really helpful when monitoring a single process. However, this tool doesn't provide CPU usage information at all. I was wondering if it's possible to get the total CPU usage that a process is taking up through eBPF. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks!